# Spark word Count Error in IntelliJ due to scala 2.12.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   scala/Product$class at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkConf$DeprecatedConfig.(SparkConf.scala:762)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.(SparkConf.scala:615) at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.(SparkConf.scala) at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:84) at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:73) at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkConf.setMaster(SparkConf.scala:105)

```
package bigdata.spark_applications
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
object WordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("WordCount")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val data = sc.textFile("C:\\Users\\scala.txt")
    val result = data.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map(word => (word , 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
    result.collect.foreach(println)
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Hello I got the answer ,

I was using the scala 2.12.1 and spark-core is not available for 2.12.1 so in project i used scala 2.11.8 and changed spark-core to 2.11 in dependency

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0"

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer for this. I was stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @PanwarS87 No Probs